# I have an array that breaks error_log(), but not print_r(), and works perfectly otherwise

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling

I am either missing something, or have found a bug in PHP 5.6.17.

I have an array of data which when I put it through error_log() (edit: Using print_r($array, true), so I am passing a string) I get;

```
Array
(
    [
```

Where I'd normally expect to see;

```
Array
(
[person_id]=> 123456
)
```

It's as if the first array key is terminating output, but the first array key is an empty subarray with nothing strange about it.

Strangely, when I use print_r(), it prints the array just fine, and all array based PHP functions that manipulate arrays, or iterate over them have no issue with the array.

Some of my keys are like this;

```
Array
(
[per_roles] => Array
    (
    )

[per_roles_retrieved] => 
[per_cache] => Array
    (
    )

[*member] => 
[*addresses] => 
[*marketing_preferences] => 
[*suppliers] => 
[_table] => address
[id] => 454545
[*exists] => 1
[*_related_objects] => Array
    (
    )

[*_related_object] => Array
    (
    )
[first_name] => John
[middle_name] => 
[last_name] => Smith

)
```

What is the issue, and is it the asterisks?

Comment: I've found the answer. The issue is that the array comes from an object that's cast as an array. Protected properties of that object when cast as an array get their keys prepended with null characters, to "protect" them. Those null chars cause error_log (once been through print_r($var, true)) to think it's reached the end of the string, so the output stops. To fix it, you'd have to str_replace those null chars, or use print_r instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php the error_log() function takes a string as an argument, not an array. Try to convert the array into a string before calling error_log().

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't explain why it gets that far. I'd expect a typical "function expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given" error.

Comment: I have no explanation for that behaviour. But you can simply use the json_encode() function to solve the problem with error_log().

Comment: Sorry, I missed something from the question, I've updated it. I am using print_r($array, true) to pass the array to error log, so I am actually passing a string. There's something about that string that it doesn't handle. If I do the same but pass a simpler test array (or any other, multidimensional array containing arrays and arrays of objects, it's never failed before.

Comment: I just tested that using PHP Version 5.5 on windows 7. I do get the expected result. Maybe there is indeed a bug in PHP 5.6.17 or there is a problem with the PHP Setup on your machine. I would advice to try the same on different computers and PHP Versions.

Comment: Hi, See my comment on the question. I've found the answer. It may be reproducible by you if you cast an object with protected properties as an array then put that through print_r($var, true) then into error_log. The casting add null chars to protected properties and that stops output.